# How to Integrate pyqt with Python Schemdraw

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am a student studying programming in Korea.
I am currently creating a pyqt flow chart, but it is not connected.
Please let me know if there is a problem with my code. Thank you.

It's my first time posting it here, is this how I do it?

안녕하세요 현재 Qtpy와 schemdraw을 연동하고 싶은데, 안되어 물어봅니다.
처음 하는거라서 어떻게 할지 고민끝에 연락드립니다.
혹시 어떻게 하는지 알려주실 수 있나요?

### my code :

```
import sys
import schemdraw
from schemdraw import flow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QToolTip, QPushButton, QApplication


def print_hi(name):
    print(f'Hi, {name}')


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        d = schemdraw.Drawing()
        d.add(flow.Start(w=2, h=2, label="START"))
        d.add(flow.Arrow('down', l=2, color='a'))
        cond1 = d.add(flow.Decision(S="No", E="YES", label="b"))

        d.add(flow.Arrow('down', xy=cond1.S, l=2))
        cond2 = d.add(flow.Decision(W="No", E="Yes", label="c"))

        d.add(flow.Line('left', xy=cond2.W, l=1))
        d.add(flow.Arrow('down', l=2))
        d.add(flow.Box(label="d"))

        d.add(flow.Line('right', xy=cond2.E, l=1))
        d.add(flow.Arrow('down', l=2))
        box = d.add(flow.Box(label="e"))
        d.add(flow.Arrow('left', xy=box.W, l=3))

        d.add(flow.Line('right', xy=cond1.E, l=5, color='red'))
        d.add(flow.Arrow('down', l=1, color='red'))
        cond3 = d.add(flow.Decision(S="No", E="Yes", label="f"))

        d.add(flow.Arrow('down', xy=cond3.S, l=3))
        d.add(flow.Box(label="g"))

        d.add(flow.Line('right', xy=cond3.E, l=2, color='red'))
        d.add(flow.Arrow('down', l=4, color='red'))
        d.add(flow.Box(label="h", color='red'))

        QToolTip.setFont(QFont('SansSerif', 10))

        self.setToolTip('This is <b>Qwidget</b> a widget')
        btn = QPushButton('Button', self)
        btn.setToolTip("This is a <b>QPushButton</b> widget")
        btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())
        btn.move(50, 50)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('ToolTips')
        self.show()

    enter code here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236, and explain: How do you test the code? What happens when you do that, and how is that different from what is supposed to happen? That is, what does "not connected" mean here? It looks like you create a `schemdraw.Drawing` named `d`, but - then what? Why should the GUI know anything about this object, or what to do with it, or how?

Comment: What is this bit in Korean?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Qt to use the schemdraw image somehow. One way would be to create a QPixmap, load it with the schemdraw image in PNG format, and add that QPixmap to a QLabel:

```
    image = QPixmap()
    image.loadFromData(d.get_imagedata('png'))
    label = QLabel(self)
    label.setPixmap(image)
```